# Make user fill at least 1 out of 3 fields to search

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I want the user to fill at least 1 out of 3 fields in the search form is it possible? 
here is the link

http://img.needforgaming.x10.mx/procurar.php

i dont want user to have empty fields and search to apper all the data...

Comment: Yes it is possible, how have you tried so far?

Comment: @DanBracuk only javaScript?

Comment: who the hell upvotes this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `procurar.php` file you should apply the check condition.

Use the below code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btn_procurar'])){
   if(empty($_REQUEST["Cliente_procurar"]) && empty($_REQUEST["N24H_procurar"]) && empty($_REQUEST["NS24_procurar"])) {
      echo "Please fill At least a field";
   } else {

     //your code to search and other
   }
}
```

Above code is server side if you want to check it client side then use the javascript.

Comment: Can i make it appear error msg only after hiting button?           That worked just fine :)

Comment: @TonySantos yes sure I am updating my answer and use that.

Answer (score 2):

Use client side or server side validation for it. You just need to check if anyone of the three textboxes has a value or not. OR all the text boxes having empty values. In javascript, you can check it as follows:

```
if((document.getElementById('text1').value == '') && (document.getElementById('text2').value == '') && (document.getElementById('text3').value == ''))
{
alert('Enter any values for search');
return false;
}
```

Comment: Ideally you should never rely solely on client side validation as it is trivial to circumvent, for anything that has any significance, you should always validate server side to ensure that what you have is what you think you should have, even if the data is supposed to be validated on the client before sending.

Answer (score 2):

```
You can do it using PHP

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!empty($_POST['search1'])||!empty($_POST['search2'])||!empty($_POST['search3'])){
        echo "Do Search";
    }
    else{
        echo "you mush fill at least one field";
    }

}



?>

<form action="" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="search1">
    <input type="text" name="search2">
    <input type="text" name="search3">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write  javascript code to check:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
 $(function () {
   $(document.forms[0]).submit(function () {
      canSubmit = false;
      $('form input:text').each (function () {
          if($(this).val().length > 0) 
               canSubmit = true;

      });
      return canSubmit;
   });
 });

<script>
```

Comment: Using jQuery just for this piece of code .. isn't that a bit too much?

Comment: Also trusting client side validation without any server side validation?

Answer (score 1):

```
function verification()
{
  var1= document.getElementById("formProcurar").value;
  var2= document.getElementById("formProcurar").value;
  var3= document.getElementById("formProcurar").value;

  if((var1 != "") && (var2 != "") && (var3 != ""))
  {
     // do what ever you want here.
  }
  else
  {
     alert("Fill at least one field");
  }

}
```

---

Use java script for the task this will be user friendly as the page does not need to refresh